# Рабочий процесс/workflow когда надо поддерживать много веток исходного кода

Tags: c, git-branch, workflow

Текущая ситуация с кодом на С для железа в нашей компании:

1. писать приходится для нескольких устройств;
2. каждое устройство имеет несколько модификаций, что влияет на
   исходники;
3. надо поддерживать несколько версий кода для каждой модификации
   железа.

В результате постоянно встаёт вопрос контроля за попаданием каждой правки исходного кода в нужные ветки системы контроля версий. При этом инженер исправив ошибку в коде под конкретную модель железа зачастую не знает где ещё данное решение может понадобиться.

Хотелось бы узнать какими системами/подходами/workflow пользуются в подобной ситуации. Может существуют программы которые позволяют наглядно отображать связи между: branch, commits, bugs... и проставлять для каждой правки куда ещё её надо портировать.

Comment: Хороше зарекомендовала себя система Git, Могу порекомендовать  книгу [Pro GIT](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1) - в ней хороше описаны основы и принципы работы.

Comment: Git у нас используется, но он общую картину не покажет. Предполагаю, что надо написать свой plugin для Redmine или вообще отдельное приложение...

Comment: Другими словами когда смотрим на задачу или bug, то должно быть очевидно в какие ветки уже попали правки, а в какие нет, ну и нужна конечно возможность отмечать ветки в которые не надо переносить правки.